# Looping though Worksheets - Hiding non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, vba

In a workbook I want to loop through all worksheets and depending on a keyword in a certain cell of each worksheet, I'd like to hide some non-contiguous columns in the respective worksheet.
I have no problems hiding a single column or multiple, contiguous columns but it does not work when I set multiple, non-contiguous columns as my range.

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    i = Worksheets.Count

    For x = 1 To i 
        Worksheets(x).Range("A:AX").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        If InStr(1, Worksheets(x).Range("A1").Value, "keyword", 1) <> 0 Then
            Worksheets(x).Range("D:E, G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Worksheets(x).Range("A:AX").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next x 
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work?

A workaround would, of course, be to add all the columns separately but I'd prefer to do it in the shorter way and of course, I'd like to understand more about VBA. I am a beginner with VBA, by the way.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? Error code, for example?

Comment: The error I get is "Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". Since the sub does what it is supposed to do when a single column or multiple contiguous columns are given as the range for the columns to be hidden, I assume that there is some syntax error that I am not aware of, meaning that in my scenario for some reason it is not posisble to give a range of multiple, non-contiguous columns.

Comment: Hmmm. `Range("D:E, G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` works just fine in a blank workbook. What is the sheet like? And you can hide those columns manually without any problem?

Comment: I tried that again without the loop and it did not work either (though it did before), so then I just restarted excel and now the code I posted above works... Restarting excel seems to have done it and now I feel stupid for asking that question. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Eh no need to feel stupid. After all, you weren't sure about the syntax. The important thing is that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for your `Else` statement if you have made all relevant columns visible beforehand.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideColumns()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    i = Worksheets.Count

    For x = 1 To i

        Worksheets(x).Range("A:AX").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        If InStr(1, Worksheets(x).Range("A1").Value, "keyword", 1) <> 0 Then
            Worksheets(x).Range("D:E, G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Other than that small problem, our code works as expected.

Comment: Nice work.  Dennis, pay attention to the indenting and style of this post.